# Como adicionar uma mesma substring em várias colunas no R

Tags: r, apply, concatenação-de-string

Tenho uma base com 2 linhas e 68 observações chamada "varnomes" e gostaria de adicionar a palavra "PF" no fim de cada observação.
Com isso, tentei utilizar a função paste:

```
varnomes<-paste(varnomes,"PF")
```

Porém, não obtive sucesso.

As primeiras três colunas da minha base são assim, por exemplo:

```
a b c
g r v
```

E quero que fiquem:

```
aPF bPF cPF
gPF rPF vPF
```

Alguma sugestão com apply ou com outra função?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a mesma base `df` criada pelo @José:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, paste0, "PF")
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso:

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c("a","b","c"),var2=c("g","r","v"),stringsAsFactors=F)
df[]<-paste0(unlist(df[]),"PF")
```

Comment: Obrigado, José! Deu certo com as duas respostas, mas infelizmente tenho que escolher uma e achei a do Carlos mais simples.